# I want report in the order in which I have executed my test-cases. How can I configure it?

Tags: java, selenium, reportng

I'm running my automation suite with Selenium and Java with ReportNG as a reporting tool. When my test-runs are over I am getting the reportNG report in ascending order.

I want the report in the order in which they have been executed.

How can I do/configure that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In TestNG report, We get this information in index.html (Chronological view). Not sure about reportNG

Comment: Thanks - Since we are running ReportNG suites which need to be presented to management. We must go with ReportNG and not TestNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to add ReportNG source files to your project. You can find them at https://github.com/dwdyer/reportng

Then you need to edit TestResultComparator.class. Change compare method for this:

```
Long a = Long.valueOf(result1.getStartMillis());
Long b = Long.valueOf(result2.getStartMillis());
return a.compareTo(b);
```

This will order your Test Methods chronologically.

After that edit TestClassComparator.class. Change compare method for this:

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf(class1.getXmlClass().getIndex());
Integer b = Integer.valueOf(class2.getXmlClass().getIndex());

return a.compareTo(b);
```

It will order your Test Classes chronologically.

Comment: I have downloaded the same. Can you please tell me how to create JAR of it and attach it to the project's Maven dependency? Any link would be helpful.

Comment: Hey, it was working like a rocket. Thanks a ton. One of my most puzzled question is solved.